# Z-star Vimicro webcam black white output instead of color

Tags: 11.10, webcam, gstreamer, cheese

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I've found that my webcam output is in black & white. In ubuntu 11.04 everything worked fine, now I've tested my webcam with skype and cheese: neither is working properly! Any hint?

This is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0ac8:301b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. ZC0301 Webcam
```

and here is an image captured from cheese (misplaced colour channels?)

[image: Looks like colour channels are misplaced]

Comment: When you get a chance post your edit as an answer so we can close this question and just point people to the right bug report, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this bug was just reported but no fix with updates: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/838739